# How to get result from two different table with one single input

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two different tables with different column name

Table 1 users

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|  id |   name   | username| image   |   email    |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
|  1  |  John1   | exmple1 |  img1   |a@gmail.com |
|  2  |  John2   | exmple2 |  img2   |b@gmail.com |
|  3  |  John3   | exmple3 |  img3   |c@gmail.com |
|  4  |  John4   | exmple4 |  img4   |d@gmail.com |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Table 2nd Company

```
+-----+----------+------------+---------=------+-----------+
|  id |company_name | username|  description   |   founded |
+-----+-------------+---------+----------------+-----------|
|  1  |    john1    | exmple1 |description1    |    2016   |
|  2  |CompanyName2 | exmple2 |description2    |    2016   |
|  3  |CompanyName3 | exmple3 |description3    |    2016   |
|  4  |CompanyName4 | exmple4 |description4    |    2016   |
+-----+-------------+---------+---------=------+-----------+
```

Now whenever a user type any input in search bar an ajax request is made to php file which checks for if that name of user exist in database or not

so for example if user type input `john` then a query should run which will check john in users table and company table & if there is a user name john & if there is a company named john it should fetch both the result.

how can i achieve this, i tried using UNION in my query but it said columns are different

Currently this is my query

```
$go = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT name, img,username FROM users WHERE name LIKE '$q%' LIMIT 0,10");
```

Now people might be thinking what i really want!
i want a single query that will check for input in both table & fetch their details

Comment: Is there any relation between two table?

Comment: @Sudnep no there is no relation

Comment: select * from users u, company c where u.username = c.username and c.username="some user name"

Comment: or.. select * from users u join company c on u.username = c.username and c.username= "something"

Comment: you can use **UNION ALL** for this case

Comment: @Sudnep UNION will not work because users table have `name` column & company table has `company_name` column ! column must be same

Comment: @AniketSingh it will if you define the columns in your select statement and make the queries match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union

```
select  id,  name  ,username, image, email, null, null
from users
where name LIKE concat('$q', '%')
union all
select  id,  company_name as name  ,username, null, null, description, founded 
from Company 
where name LIKE concat('$q, '%')
order by name limit 10
```

Comment: i already wrote in my post that I've tried UNION it will not work because company table columns are different & they are not related to each other

Comment: you can easily expand the columns to ensure that they are formally equa

Comment: I have update the answer with expanded column  .for union

Comment: your query worked but only brought one result but in my database there are 3  results. check here http://prntscr.com/betl5z

Comment: In the image you have two different name for firts select and second  select  .. 'aniket' and 'eclercx'  should be the same for the right work .., anyway i have update the answer with union all

Comment: I think the problem here is it will match even if only 1 table contains your search criteria. OP wanted the name being searched to exist on both sides

Comment: I suggested  also the use of concat for proper build the like condition .. i have update the answer also with this

Comment: Thanks for your help